# Want to convert multiple json objects to an array in angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Requirement is : an automation test suite will run. in the teardown activity i am running a java program which will fetch data from excel and generate a JSON file. Json file is being generated properly. Now i am maintaining a single file, lets say Repository for JSON, which will be having an entry for each and every generated files.

I can do it with java, filewriter having true as the second argument of constructor,and make an entry of newly generated JSON file inside JSONrepository file like below/

```
{"testSuiteID" : 1, "testSuiteName" : "Dummy Name", "timestamp":"1jan2017_8_00_pm", "testsuite_JSONfile" : "IamNewlyGeneratedJSON.json"},
{"testSuiteID" : 2, "testSuiteName" : "Dummy Name2", "timestamp":"1jan2017_820_pm", "testsuite_JSONfile" : "IamNewlyGeneratedJSON_2.json"}
```

Now, i making an $http.get request from angular to fetch the content of this file.

I want this to be an array of

```
[{"testSuiteID" : 1, "testSuiteName" : "Dummy Name", "timestamp":"1jan2017_8_00_pm", "testsuite_JSONfile" : "IamNewlyGeneratedJSON.json"},
{"testSuiteID" : 2, "testSuiteName" : "Dummy Name2", "timestamp":"1jan2017_820_pm", "testsuite_JSONfile" : "IamNewlyGeneratedJSON_2.json"}]
```

That is nothing but square brackets inserted at beginning and ending of file. though that can be done from java as well, but i am trying to avoid that overhead.

Can i do it with javascript/jquery/angular ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused as to what exactly you're trying to do. Are you trying to write to the JSON file from JavaScript?

Comment: No, its just i am trying to read it. and converting all the json objects to an array, so that i can iterate over it using ng-repeat.

Comment: Well, your first example is not valid JSON. Your objects need to be inside square brackets `[]` as they are an array of items. I would be curious to see what `console.log(response.data)` puts out inside your `$http.get` callback. I reckon it's probably just a string, in which case you can just append `[` and `]` around it, and do `JSON.parse()` on your new string

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to convert it to Array, you can use **[JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)**

```js
var result = [];

var in1 = '{"testSuiteID" : 1, "testSuiteName" : "Dummy Name", "timestamp":"1jan2017_8_00_pm", "testsuite_JSONfile" : "IamNewlyGeneratedJSON.json"},{"testSuiteID" : 2, "testSuiteName" : "Dummy Name2", "timestamp":"1jan2017_820_pm", "testsuite_JSONfile" : "IamNewlyGeneratedJSON_2.json"}';

result=JSON.parse("["+in1+"]");

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little weird what you're trying to do, but ideally the endpoint should be returning a proper JSON array in your situation.

If you're trying to wrap it around square brackets it's just simple string manipulation.

```
var json = "{}"

function wrapInBrackets(myStr) {
  return '[' + myStr + ']'
}
```

To convert it to a proper json object, you need to use JSON.parse()

```
var obj = JSON.parse(wrapInBrackets(json));
```

Comment: You should probably include something about using `JSON.parse()` on the new string, since they OP is asking for an array, not a string